# 404 Not Found on load from Jena into Blazegraph

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, blazegraph

I have a simple piece of code using Jena's RDFConnection to load rdf into Blazegraph, but keep getting HTTP 404 Not found:

```
public void simpleLoad() {
    String service = "http://localhost:8889/bigdata";
  try ( RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(service) ) {
    conn.load("/Users/rf/test2.rdf") ;
  //Txn.executeWrite(conn, ()-> {
     //conn.load("/Users/rf/test2.rdf") ;
  //});
  } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
  }
}
```

Sparql requests work fine for this service url.
I tried to call connect() with more detailed urls, like

```
connect(service, service, "http://localhost:8889/bigdata/dataloader")
```

which was mentioned somewhere, but this resulted in HTTP 400 Bad request instead.

Probably worth mentioning that Blazegraph is running in Docker in my setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to you Blazegraph Workbench. Select the Namespaces tab. For you namespace click "Service Description". That will create a `sparql.rdf`. Open that and search for `sparqlEndpoint`. That is IRI you need to use for `RDFConnection`. Then

```
  RDFConnection conn = RDFConnectionFactory.connect(service);
  conn.load(data);
  conn.close();
```

should work.